# Consutla SQL en relacion muchos a muchos

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo 3 tablas que no logro dar con el resultado esperado en mi consulta. Ya intente hacer 2 JOIN pero me sigue dando un resultado no esperado.

Las 3 tablas son las siguiente
stoauto - (stock de autos que hay, donde sa_marca es la clave primaria de la tabla marca, y sa_auto es la clave primaria de la tabla autos), stoauto es la tabla intermedia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

marca - nombre de las marcas de los autos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

auto - nombres de los autos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La relacion deberia de ser la siguiente, un stock de auto posee una marca y un nombre de auto.
Una marca tiene muchos autos
un auto tiene una única marca

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos ya creada y de la cual unicamente poseo usuario de consulta por lo que no puedo modificar nada.

Ya probe lo siguiente

```
SELECT 
stoauto.sa_codigo,
marca.mar_nombre,
auto.au_nombre
FROM marca
JOIN stoauto ON marca.mar_codigo = stoauto.sa_marca
JOIN auto ON auto.au_codigo = stoauto.sa_auto
WHERE stoauto.sa_tipo=5
```

Y me da el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me debería traer un único código con un único nombre de marca y un único modelo de auto. Pero me trae repetido el código varias veces

El where de sa_tipo=5 es para que me traiga unicamente las operaciones que son de venta de 0km que se identifican con ese codigo

Comment: `GROUP BY stoauto.sa_codigo, marca.mar_nombre, auto.au_nombre`

Comment: Recien leyendo mas datos de la tabla tiene otra dificultad mas, el valor auto.au_codigo no es unico, existe el 1 para la marca 1, el 1 para la marca 2, el 1 para la marca 3 y asi sucesivamente

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en el diseño de tus tablas. La marca no debería ser parte de la tabla de stock de autos porque la marca es un atributo del auto y no directamente del stock. Se puede solucionar usando la relación adecuada.

```
SELECT 
    s.sa_codigo,
    m.mar_nombre,
    a.au_nombre
FROM stoauto s 
JOIN auto    a ON s.sa_auto = a.au_codigo
JOIN marca   m ON a.au_marca = m.mar_codigo
WHERE s.sa_tipo = 5;
```

Comment: Ya hice eso y sigue dando un resultado equivocado. Lamentablemente no tengo como cambiar el diseño de la base de datos porque ya tiene registros y mi usuario no es para modificar. Se puede ir aplicando filtros a la consulta y luego generar una consulta a apartir de ese filtro? se me ocurre primero filtrar el tipo de op que quiero, luego el tipo de marca , luego el auto y asi. o hacer una busqueda de claves convinadas tipo concatenar auto-marca y buscala en la tabla stoauto y que coincida con las 2 columans de marca y auto

Comment: ¿Qué es un resultado equivocado? Estás mostrando todas las filas del stock con la información de cada auto y su marca. El código del stock debería ser único en la consulta, a menos de que no sea la llave primaria como indicaría su nombre.